# Django Ajax Post request

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-templates, csrf-token

Error is: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /tracker/

i try a URL : tracker, tracker/, /tracker/, [http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/'](http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/%27)

I'm new to Django. I try many URL and I also try a Moesif CORS(Extention)

console Error is: jquery-3.5.1.js:10099 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/ 403 (Forbidden)
send @ jquery-3.5.1.js:10099
ajax @ jquery-3.5.1.js:9682
(anonymous) @ (index):276
dispatch @ jquery-3.5.1.js:5429
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.5.1.js:5233

**urls.py file**:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('preview/<int:id>/', views.preview, name="preview"),
    path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),
    path('tracker/', views.tracker, name="tracker"),
   
]
```

console.log('working')

```
$('#trackerForm').submit(function(event){

    $('#items').empty();

    var formdata = {

        'orderId' : $('input[name=order_id]').val(),
        'email' : $('input[name=email]').val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()

    };

    $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/',
        data:'formdata',
        encode: true
    })

    .done(function(data){

        console.log(data)
        updates = JSON.parse(data);
            if (updates.length > 0 & updates != {}) {
                for (i = 0; i < updates.length; i++) {
                    let text = updates[i]['text'];
                    let time = updates[i]['time'];
                    mystr = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    ${text}
                    <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">${time}</span>
                </li>`
                    $('#items').append(mystr);
                }
            } else {
                mystr = `<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    Sorry, We are not able to fetch this order id and email. Make sure to type correct order Id and email</li>`
                $('#items').append(mystr);
            }
    })

    event.preventDefault();

})
```

**Views.py**

```
def tracker(request):

   if request.method == "POST":
      order_id = request.POST.get('order_id')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      

      try:
         order = Order.objects.filter(order_id=order_id, email=email)
         if len(order) > 0:
            update = updateOrder.objects.filter(order_id=order_id)
            updates = []
            for item in update:
               updates.append({'text':item.order_desc, 'time':item.timestamp})
               responce = json.dumps(updates, default=str)
               print(responce)
            return HttpResponse(responce) 
         else:
            return HttpResponse({})
      except Exception as e:
         return HttpResponse({})

   
   context={}
   return render(request, 'cart/tracker.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `'formdata' -> formdata`

```
 formdata= {
   ... 
 }
 ...
 $.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/tracker/',
        data: formdata,
        encode: true
    })
```

Comment: tnx Bro i try to more than 2 hours

Comment: @shatishdesai haha, glad it helps

Comment: @shatishdesai if was solved your problem you should accept the answer also.